# Error:(26) error: ' ' is incompatible with attribute android:icon (attr) reference

Tags: android, debugging, manifest, program-entry-point

I am trying to hide the status bar but decided not to do so, so i did back everything but this problem exist.

errors:
**Error:(26) error: ' ' is incompatible with attribute android:icon (attr) reference.**

**Error:(26) ' ' is incompatible with attribute android:icon (attr) reference.**

**Error:failed processing manifest.**

**Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details**

**Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details**

**Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details**

**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.**

**> Failed to execute aapt**

this is the code of the main manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jsoft.jcoreports">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/hotelb"
        android:label="JCore Reports"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityNew"
            android:label="  "
            android:icon=" "
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"> </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>`
```

this the debug manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jsoft.jcoreports"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/hotelb"
        android:label="JCore Reports"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <activity android:name="com.example.jsoft.jcoreports.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.jsoft.jcoreports.ActivityNew"
            android:icon=" "
            android:label="  "
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.VERSION"
            android:value="26.1.0" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.arch.lifecycle.VERSION"
            android:value="27.0.0-SNAPSHOT" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove **`android:icon=" "`** from your `ActivityNew` activity like below code

Use this

```
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityNew"
        android:label="  "
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"> </activity>
```

Instead of this

```
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityNew"
        android:label="  "
        android:icon=" "
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"> </activity>
```

Comment: oh, yes found that error, now I remember what is the problem, thanks sir Nilu

Comment: @BDMs happy to help you